# Spherecast - enabling MeshRenderer of selector target around prefabbed object once hit and disabling Meshrenderer when not hit anymore

Tags: unity, c#, raycasting, instancing

I have an interesting problem - I have been looking up for solutions on this but I think there is something I am missing and I require a little more knowledge.

I have a scene and the scene has an Oculus OVRRig set up.  I have a script with sphereCast connected to the right hand. This Spherecast shoots out to select a particular layer.  This is all working fine.

I have also the setting of an alpha color on the cross hair brings up the object when the SphereCast hits.

[image]

It is up until here it all works fine.  It is here I reiterate that my object is a spawned prefab - which seems to be causing trouble.  I say this because I cannot select and change the material of the crossHair as it affects all the prefabs.

I simply cannot deactivate it once the SphereCast stops pointing at it.

Two Pieces of code.  The first sets up the sphere cast - attaches to a specific target and sets up a bool - Switcher - for the next scene to allocate the MeshRenderer for the crosshair.

```
public float radius;//For the radius of the SphereCast
public LayerMask LayerMask1;//The current Layer I use for focusing on the Raycasting Objects
public float MaxtDistance;// The Overall reach of the Spherecast

public GameObject currentHitObject;
public Vector3 up;
public RaycastHit hit;
public Vector3 startPos;
public int moveSpeed;
public bool TransitionSwitcher = false;
public bool Switcher = false;

void Update()
{
    startPos = transform.position;
    up = transform.forward;

    if (TransitionSwitcher)
    {
        StartCoroutine(MoveTo());
    }

    if (Physics.SphereCast(startPos, radius, up, out hit, MaxtDistance, LayerMask1, QueryTriggerInteraction.UseGlobal))
    {
    //    Transform target = hit.collider.transform.GetChild(2).GetChild(0);
     //   target.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = true;
        // OVRInput.SetControllerVibration(0.3f, 0.3f, OVRInput.Controller.RTouch);
        TransitionSwitcher = true;
        Switcher = true;
        currentHitObject = hit.transform.gameObject;
    }
    else
    { 
        OVRInput.SetControllerVibration(0.0f, 0.0f, OVRInput.Controller.RTouch);
        Switcher = false;
    }

}
IEnumerator MoveTo()
{
    hit.collider.gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(hit.transform.position, startPos, Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed);
    TransitionSwitcher = false;
    yield return null;
}
```

This second piece of code takes the Bool Switcher from the code above and either switches on or off the renderer.  I know why it isn't working properly in this - it allocates the boolean to all the prefabs this is attached to.

```
public GameObject cube;
public GameObject crossHair;
public bool result = false;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    cube = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
    crossHair.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
}

void Update()
{
    bool result = cube.GetComponent<Sphere2>().Switcher;
    print(result);

    if (result == true)
    {
        print("on");
        OVRInput.SetControllerVibration(0.3f, 0.3f, OVRInput.Controller.RTouch);
        crossHair.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = true;
    }
    else if (result == false)
    {
        print("off");
        OVRInput.SetControllerVibration(0.0f, 0.0f, OVRInput.Controller.RTouch);
        crossHair.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction with this?  It doesn't have to be the solution handed to me - rather how do I turn specific meshrenderers on and off when my spherecast hits them and leaves their reach respectively?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it in a Eureka but feeling dumb moment.  So maybe this will be useful to someone out there - so they don't spend an entire day on it too.

I used a temp variable.  Boy don't I feel silly.

Anyways here's the code (cut down a little):

```
    public Transform TempTarget;

void Update()
{
    startPos = transform.position;
    up = transform.forward;

    if (TransitionSwitcher)
    {
        StartCoroutine(MoveTo());
    }

    if (Physics.SphereCast(startPos, radius, up, out hit, MaxtDistance, LayerMask1, QueryTriggerInteraction.UseGlobal))
    {
      Transform target = hit.collider.transform.GetChild(2).GetChild(0);
      TempTarget = target;
        target.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = true;
        TransitionSwitcher = true;
        currentHitObject = hit.transform.gameObject;
    }
    else
    { 
        OVRInput.SetControllerVibration(0.0f, 0.0f, OVRInput.Controller.RTouch);
        TempTarget.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;//
       // Switcher = false;
    }

}
```